# Why strong limit cardinals in the definition of condensed sets?

Tags: ct.category-theory, condensed-mathematics

A condensed set à la Clausen–Scholze is, as far as I understand it, a small sheaf on the large site of profinite spaces. In [Scholze's notes](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf) they are described as being objects of a category that is a large sequential colimit of toposes, each of which is $\mathrm{Sh}(*_{\kappa\text{-proét}})$, where the index $\kappa$ runs over the uncountable strong limit cardinals. The $\kappa$-proétale site $*_{\kappa\text{-proét}}$ consists of the profinite spaces whose underlying set is smaller than $\kappa$ (the topology is for now not important). The inclusions of sites induce fully faithful inverse image functors between the toposes, and the colimit defining the condensed sets is given by the colimit along these inverse image functors.

We can concretely describe this colimit as having objects pairs $(\kappa,F)$ consisting of an uncountable strong limit cardinal and a sheaf on $*_{\kappa\text{-proét}}$, where a map $(\kappa,F) \to (\kappa',G)$ is a map of sheaves on $*_{\lambda\text{-proét}}$ where $\lambda = \max\{\kappa,\kappa'\}$ where we have included the sheaf in the smaller topos into the larger topos (i.e. extended it to the larger site in the usual way).

Now I would like to know what goes wrong if I don't take this limit only over uncountable strong limit cardinals, but rather over all cardinals. (In this setup, a condensed set would be a pair consisting of an arbitrary cardinal $\mu$ and a sheaf on $*_{\mu\text{-proét}}$; morphisms are as above.) The strong limit cardinals just give a cofinal sequence, and it's not clear to me that the result is not equivalent. If there are specific properties of strong limit cardinals that are used, what are they?

Comment: I mean, *any* colimit of a diagram indexed by all cardinals is equivalent to its restriction to strong limit cardinalities, by the definition of cofinality, right? So it seems clear that there can be no issue here except with whether $\mu-\text{proét}$ even exists for arbitrary $\mu$.

Comment: @KevinArlin I'm not so much worried about $*_{\mu\text{-proét}}$ - it's the category profinite sets smaller than $\mu$ with jointly surjective finite families of maps as covers. The only place I could see something odd potentially happening is in the geometric morphism between the categories of sheaves.

Comment: Ah, right, well, the categories of $\kappa$-condensed sets are all Grothendieck toposes, so any continuous functor between them admits a left adjoint, and the forgetful functors are certainly continuous. No? So I see no way there’s a need for the restriction to strong limits here. Maybe to be sure that the free $\kappa-$profinite set on a $\kappa$-small set exists.

Comment: @KevinArlin yes, I really must be missing something because otherwise I don't know why Clausen and Scholze restrict to strong limit $\kappa$. As long as the inverse image functors are fully faithful for arbitrary cardinals, I don't know of any reason to make that restriction (there might be one, I just don't know it!)

Comment: If I remember correctly, you use strong limit cardinals to have the free profinite sets at your disposal, and you use this for technical lemmas about the extension functors. Now this does not matter for the *definition*, but it will matter for statements about limits and colimits in the colimit category (that they can be computed locally, this sort of thing)

Comment: I just had a quick look at the notes, and indeed this is used for instance in Propositions 2.3, 2.5, to compare sheaves on the $\kappa$-proétale site, and sheaves on the smaller site of profinite (or extremally disconnected) spaces. This comparison is later used to get all the nice behaviours of limits and colimits in condensed sets/abelian groups, see e.g. theorem 2.2 and proposition 2.9. iirc, it's important to them to have the pov that condensed = (hypercomplete in the $\infty$-categorical case) sheaves on the whole proétale site, but it is technically convenient to restrict to profinite

Comment: or extremally disconnected spaces

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Hmm, ok. Though, to be fair, one could put it the other way around: give the more generous definition (arbitrary cardinals) for condensed sets, then note that wlog one can reduce to the case of strong limit if need be, then use this fact in constructions/proofs. Maybe it's a matter of taste, but I prefer the definition with fewer technical side conditions, and would leave that to lemmas. Thanks, though, for digging out specific statements where the strong limit condition is used!

Comment: As Maxime noted above, the "strong limit" assumption is needed to show various different definitions of $\kappa$-condensed sets agree (based on compact Hausdorff, profinite, or extr disc). Also, $\kappa$-condensed abelian groups wouldn't be generated by compact projectives for general $\kappa$. You could of course allow more general $\kappa$ and the large colimit of these categories stays the same, but the individual layers lack any good properties, so better stay away from them.

Comment: David : I was going to answer something along the lines of Peter's comment : there are also other proofs where you study the "individual layers" and you need to isolate the strong limit cases for those. In the end you would have a bunch of statements starting with "when $\kappa$ is strong limit", and I think they just chose to have it as a standing assumption once and for all.

Comment: @PeterScholze straight from the horse's mouth! Thanks for confirming my suspicion, and clarifying your motivation (as deduced by Maxime). An answer from either of you in the box below means I can mark it as officially accepted.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi (see comment to Peter; I can't tag both of you in one comment)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me write down an answer to mark the question as answered.

As David points out, the definition would not change if one used all cardinals $\kappa$ instead of the strong limit ones, as the latter are cofinal in the former.

But strong limit cardinals are used to study the "individual layers" appearing in the definition : $\kappa$-condensed sets/abelian groups etc.

To prove that one can compare those to sheaves on $\kappa$-small profinite sets, or $\kappa$-small extremally disconnected sets, one uses that $\kappa$ is strong limit; see propositions 2.3, 2.5 of the notes and their proofs.

In turn, this comparison is very useful technically speaking, as sheaves on the site of $\kappa$-small extremally disconnected sets are just product preserving functors, and thus the category of sheaves enjoys very nice properties (with respect to co/limits for instance); and also the functors that connect these categories of sheaves are also particularly well-behaved, which allows one to make "local" computations of co/limits, which is again useful to prove specific things about their behaviour. For examples of this, see proposition 2.9 and theorem 2.2 of the notes.

As Peter pointed out in the comments, another thing that's good in $\kappa$-condensed abelian groups that doesn't work in general, but does if $\kappa$ is strong limit, is the fact that they are generated by compact projectives.

Comment: Concretely, the reason you need strong limit to get nice layers is that there are $2^{2^{|X|}}$-many ultrafilters on a set $|X|$ and extremally disconnected spaces are spaces of ultrafilters, right?

Comment: @TimCampion : they're retracts of them, but yes that's what's happening! You want your $V_\kappa$ to be closed under "projective resolutions" of your spaces and that will involve taking spaces of ultrafilters. I explained in the comments (part of) why you'd want that !